# Late bind name in Unity Injection

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm trying to get the following code to work:

```
        _container.RegisterType<string>(
            new InjectionFactory((ctr, @type, name) =>
                SomeDictionary[name]));
```

It is not working however, because the string above is being registered without a name.

However the name is not known at the time of registration. I need to somehow be able to late bind the name to the time of resolution.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why you have to register `string` type into container?

Comment: It's just an example, it can be an IStuff for all that matters. And I have a Dictionary<string,IStuff> and I want to get the right IStuff based on the resolution name that isn't determined at registration time.

Comment: Please expand your question by adding the complete picture incl. where the dictionary resides, where and when name/instance pairs are added to it, what it's purpose is, etc. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @David What's there to disclose? I just want to late bind the name. I can do this with open generics and only have it resolve correctly in the factory. I want to do the same with the name. That's all there's.

Answer (score 2):

This is not supported by default in the Unity container. You could possibly write a container extension to get it to work, but I wouldn't go down that route before trying alternate approaches first.

You've said *what* you want to do. *Why* do you want to do it? Understanding the underlying goal would help in figuring out other ways to accomplish your objectives.

Comment: I am trying to inject query string from my restful api, into any parameter in the manager constructor. This is used because we have a multi-tenant architecture, and some pieces of the query string is used to determine how the managers behave. There is a work around for sure, but being able to do the above would be neat.